# What is your favorite video/screen capturing tool for the iPhone simulator?

Tags: iphone, simulator

I'm about to publish a new web site design with all of my iPhone apps, and I would like to display a video demonstration of the iPhone apps in an embedded video on the web page. I need recommendations for a video capturing tool that would run on a Mac, and record the interaction of the user with the app on the iPhone simulator.

I tried SimCap, and it's so buggy I cannot make it work with iOS4 and Xcode 3.23. I also tried ScreenFlow, but the video didn't turn out like I wanted.

Any recommendations of other video capturing tools for the iPhone simulator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like SimFinger:  http://blog.atebits.com/2009/03/not-your-average-iphone-screencast/

As far as screen capturing goes,  Snapz Pro X is decent, but its not freeware :(  Especially when the trial runs out, then it just turns into annoyware.

Comment: Thanks, I tried SimFinger and that was the missing piece to make the mouse pointer the white semi-transparent circle. I'm using ScreenFlow to convert the video, and it's looking good so far.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with [Jing](http://www.jingproject.com/). I like it. The output is a flash file. The animation is recorded well, output file is small as well

Comment: thanks for posting this, i've been looking for something like this for a while and this was perfect!

Comment: Default Mac OS X Quicktime player also has a possibility to record screen, but its captured area aspect ratio is quite strange.